# Template is not displayed

Tags: magento-1.9

I add this in my controller, but if go to mysite.loc/module/controller/downloadPdf I show white window.

```
public function downloadPdfAction(){
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock('gent/orders_pdf')->setTemplate('gent/orders/pdf.phtml');
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
```

What I forgot to do?

Comment: Have you tried PHP error reporting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try below code.

```
 public function downloadPdfAction(){
            $this->loadLayout();
           echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('gent/orders_pdf')->setTemplate('gent/orders/pdf.phtml')->toHtml();
            $this->renderLayout();
        }
```

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to load layout before `getLayout` function and append your block to content.

```
public function downloadPdfAction(){
                $this->loadLayout();
                $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('gent/orders_pdf')->setTemplate('gent/orders/pdf.phtml');
                $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
                $this->renderLayout();
}
```